# Cad ingesting SDK that supports STEP , Parasolid and Solidworks filetypes and Also Meshing

Tags: mesh, cad

We have an internal CSG (Constructive Solid Geometry) format.Converting/Ingesting other CSG-based files to our internal format is straightforward. We also managed to convert some polygon (mesh) based geometries to our internal format.

But we also want to support **B-Rep** files such as ***Step*** and ***Parasolid***.We want to able to use a library that

- Supports .NET/ c#  (ideally .NET standard)
- Can import Step and Parasolid and also can do meshing on these surfaces and faces..
- Can import Solidworks and ideally as many as possible CAD/CAM/CAE file formats
- Extensible

*OpenCascade*,*C3D*, and *CadExchanger* are some options but are there more options in this space?

Comment: The way i see it its not so much about reading the step file. But rather that step files are b-rep models is the problem.  Reading in a step file is not really all that problematic, the problem is when you want to interpret it. In order for you to make any sense of the file you need to have a b-rep engine. There are few of them out there available for purchase. First parasolid itself is licensable, then theres PTCs granite, coretechnologie is alo a possibility.

Comment: yup, exactly. gonna check Granite . Also found out Open CASCADE XDE (OCAF) . Looks like it can abstract that work .